# Is It Possible to Retrieve a CA Certificate from CertificateAuthority Store

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I'm working through the .NET API for working with X509 certificates and would like to know if it is possible to retrieve a CA Certificate from CertificateAuthority Store. I have tried loads of permutations and the one that makes the most sense (but also fails) is:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var count = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, "CN=SecureTrust CA", false).Count;
store.Close();
```

That returns a count of `0`.

Comment: In certificate manager, there exists certificate with subject `CN=SecureTrust CA` ?\

Comment: You might want to re-examine the [StoreName Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename(v=vs.110).aspx). I'd have *thought* you'd want to look in `Root`, not `CertificateAuthority`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have tried Root and AuthRoot. I've run the exe as Admin. I'm out of ideas and starting to think it is not possible for one reason or another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you need to use `Root` rather than `CertificateAuthority`. Also, if you're using `FindBySubjectDistinguishedName`, you have to use the full DN.

This works:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var count = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, 
      "CN=SecureTrust CA, O=SecureTrust Corporation, C=US", false).Count;
store.Close();
```

Or use the less strict `FindBySubjectName`:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var count = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, 
                                    "SecureTrust CA", false).Count;
store.Close();
```